# Olympiad problem - struggling with polar coordinates

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems

This is a Physics Olympiad problem; and I am still struggling with it. I will quote it here:

> A particle moves along a horizontal track following the trajectory $r=r_{0}e^{-k\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle made by the position vector with the horizontal. Recall that the velocity in polar coordinates is $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}=\dot r \hat r+r \dot \theta \hat \theta$. If at $t=0, \theta=0$ the velocity is $v_{0}$, find $\theta$ dependence of velocity and the angle the velocity vector makes with the radial vector.

The answer is that $v(\theta)=v_{0}$ and is independent of $\theta$; and $\alpha(\theta)=\tan^{-1}(\pm\frac{1}{k})$ and independent of $\theta$. 
It makes sense, as the equation resembles a logarithmic spiral, and the results hold for it. But how do I prove it?

I tried differentiating it all I could, but I am always getting an extra $e^{-k\theta}$ in the term for velocity.

$\vec v=\frac{d}{dt}(r_{0}e^{-k\theta}) \hat r + r_{0}e^{-k\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$=$-kr_{0}e^{-k\theta}\dot \theta\hat r + r_{0}e^{-k\theta}\dot \theta \hat \theta$ =$r_{0}e^{-k\theta}\dot \theta(-k\hat r+\hat \theta)$. ------(1)

At $\theta=0$,

$\vec v= \vec v_{0}=r_{0}\dot \theta(-k\hat r+\hat \theta)$ ------------------(2)

But then how do I prove that (1) and (2) are the same? i.e. how do I get rid of $e^{-k\theta}$ in the first equation? Or do I have to approach it differently? But I want to stick to polar coordinates.

Please help. I am posting this after struggling for 2 straight days, and now I am completely frustrated. What's even more annoying that it is only a 4 mark (2 marks for each part) problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you posted the question exactly? I'm confused as to what the question is asking. at t=0 velocity is v0, and it's asking to prove velocity is v0? So it's asking to prove that the velocity is constant?

Comment: @AmeetSharma I have edited my question.

Comment: Hi GRrocks. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't believe this is a homework problem; I just got my hands on a few papers on the net and set about solving them. Plus I am not asking for the entire solution; just my mistake and a hint would be nice.

Comment: The only force acting on the particle is $\vec{N}$, and since $\hat{N} \cdot \hat{v} = 0$, work done by normal force is zero, hence it's kinetic energy remains constant, so $v=v_0$. For $\alpha$, it is clear that $\cos{\alpha} = \hat{v} \cdot \hat{r} = \frac{-a}{\sqrt{a^2 + 1}}$ which is a constant. Hence both $v$ and $\alpha$ remain constant throughout the motion. Proved.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no time dependence in the given equation (in other words, you have only the trajectory in terms of some parameter -- $\theta$ -- with no given connection to the time), you cannot arrive at the velocity by differentiating.

Of course $k = \cot\alpha$ for a well-chosen $\alpha$ ... ($\alpha = \arctan(k^{-1})$) :)

But why does this prove anything, did you learn some advanced features of the logarithmic spiral? I would say, to prove the constancy of the velocity you need to show that the force (i.e. the derivative of the velocity, which is given in the problem) is always perpendicular to it...

---

Well, since I do not understand what you are doing, unfortunately, and my hints don't seem to help (well, they went in another direction than the problem wants to guide you, therefore the confusion, sorry...), I will just post a direct solution...:

take the given formula $$ \vec v = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\vec r = \dot r\hat r + r\dot\theta\hat\theta$$

now use the given trajectory to reduce the number of variables: $$\dot r = \frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta}\dot\theta \mathrm{\qquad with\qquad} \frac{\mathrm dr}{\mathrm d\theta} = -kr$$

Now combine and extract the factor $r\dot\theta$: $$\vec v = r\dot\theta(
-k\hat r + \hat\theta)$$

Obviously, the direction has always the same angle (given by the vector in parentheses). The magnitude $v$ is $r\dot\theta$. There is probably a more elegant way to proceed now, but I would argue like this:

Assume $v$ is constant and show that this is a valid solution, since the solution is unique, you are done now. So, let's go:

A constant $v$ means, the force is always perpendicular to $\vec v$, and has therefore a constant angle to $\hat r$. Thus the tangential force is constant and the torque therefore is proportional to $r$.
The decrease of angular momentum (which is $mr^2\dot\theta$) has to be proportional to the torque, that is, to $r$. This is consistent, since $d/dt(r^2\dot\theta) = \dot r$ for constant $r\dot\theta$. And $r$ is proportional to $\dot r$.

Comment: I have elaborated on $\theta$; and I believe the solution is something really simple ( and we are doing something silly), as it is only a 2 mark problem.

Comment: Thanks @Ilja but how is this velocity independent of $\theta$( $r=e^{-k\theta}$)? Also, $v_{0}$ is not equal to this expression in any case, as there is always the exponential term( which won't exist at $\theta=0$).

Comment: Well, obviously the exponential term is cancelled in the $\dot\theta(t)$ - it is not time independent! You want to prove, that $r(t)\dot\theta(t)$ is time independent, that doesn't mean that $r$ is constant.
As I wrote, constant energy implies a purely normal force, and that means an angular torque which reduces the angular momentum all the time. But not so fast as $r^2$, so that $\dot\theta$ rises. And this compensates the $exp(-kt)$ in the $r(t)$.

Comment: but look at the eq. (2) in my question for $v_{0}$ and your equation for $v$.....they aren't the same; and I am supposed to prove $v=v_{0}$. And it is not in terms of $t=0$, but $\theta=0$. But thanks anyway!! I still think that we should be given a relation between the angle and the time.

Comment: Oh wait! are you saying that the direction of ( given by the unit vectors in parentheses) is independent of $\theta$, so the velocity is independent of $\theta$? but the magnitude is not(because of the exponential term), and the solution clearly asks for $v({\theta})$( show that $v(\theta)=v_{0}$)...or am I missing something?

Comment: Okay, to prove the constancy of the direction angle is simple, you have done it already, do you agree on this? 
Now to the magnitude; it is $r(t)\dot\theta(t)$. Yes, you have an exponential term in $r(t)$. But why do you think $\dot\theta(t)$ is constant? It is not. So you "just" have to show that $\dot\theta(t)$ also has an exponential term, that just cancels the one from the $r(t)$.
This is the task now. This is all you can get out of the trajectory by pure mathematics/calculation. To proceed further the kinematics of the particle is not sufficient, you need dynamical equations! (forces etc)

Comment: ohk...just in case, I found a link to the papers — http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/uploads/ino-2015-qp-and-solutions/inpho-2015-qp-sol/at_download/file. It also has a diagram for the problem( not helpful at all).